# NullReferenceException when trying to go to previous storyboard

Tags: xamarin.ios

a bit of an iOS beginner here. I am tasked with creating a button that will navigate to the previous view controller. I have tried a lot of different ways, but the most recent is as follows:

```
partial void ButtonPressedPreviousOne(UIButton sender)
    {
        UIStoryboard HomeStoryboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Home", null);
        UserProfileViewController prevController = HomeStoryboard.InstantiateViewController("User_Profile_VC") as UserProfileViewController;
        NavigationController.PopToViewController(prevController, true);
    }
```

This throws a null reference exception. I only partially understand what is meant by this. Is there something wrong with the above code or am I missing something entirely different?

Comment: first, are you actually using a NavigationController?  Second, you are creating a NEW instance of Home and trying to Pop to it - that's not how Navigation works.

Comment: I see. Yes, it is a navigation controller. I do know that much! So should it just be something like NavigationController.PopViewController(true)?

Comment: if you want to just go to the previous page in the Navigation stack, then yes

Comment: I just tried that, but it's still throwing that exception. I literally just put:

 partial void ButtonPressedPreviousOne(UIButton sender)
        {
            NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
        }

Comment: Then NavigationController must be null

Comment: I was told that it was a Navigation Controller, but I am not so sure at this point. The person I am working with has two storyboards. "Main" & "Home". He has one storyboard connecting to the other.. so there is one page that is the initial profile page and then you click "save" and it moves to the next page which is on the Main storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Navigation controller has method `NavigationController.PopViewController(true)`.
Try this one. But I strongly recommended check stack before do this like
`public bool CanGoBack => NavigationController.ViewControllers.Length > 1;`

Answer (score 0):

**Let see how navigation works**:

Push:

> To move from one page to another, an application will push a new page
>   onto the navigation stack, where it will become the active page, as
>   shown in the following diagram:

When we push a page, we usually use:

```
NavigationController.PushViewController();
```

Pop:

> To return back to the previous page, the application will pop the
>   current page from the navigation stack, and the new topmost page
>   becomes the active page, as shown in the following diagram:

When we pop a page:

If you want to go back to `previous page`, use:

```
NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
```

If you want to go back to `root page`, use:

```
NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

If you want to go back to `specific page` in `Navigation Stack`, use:

```
NavigationController.PopToViewController(viewController, true);
```

Refer : [hierarchical Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

**Back to your code**:

If you use `PopToViewController`, the `first paramater`(`prevController` in your code) should be a **existing** ViewController in `Navigation Stack` instead of a new created. You got a null reference exception because the `prevController` you created is not in your `Navigation Stack`.

In your case, you can use:

```
   var navController = this.NavigationController;

   foreach (var controller in navController.ViewControllers)
   {
       if (controller is UserProfileViewController)
          {
              NavigationController.PopToViewController(controller,true);
              break;
          }
    }
```

Note: if `UserProfileViewController` is the previous page you want to pop, use `NavigationController.PopViewController(true);` directly is simpler and faster.